# unable to access java web start using desktop link while it is accessible using web url

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jnlp

I am unable to access Java web start application using desktop shortcut while I can access it using the web URL.

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Cannot download resource. System is offline.
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
network: Connecting socket://127.0.0.1:4063 with proxy=DIRECT
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### Could not load file/URL specified: http://sample.com/sample.jnlp
```

I do not know how to configure the proxy for my java web start. I have checked the permission of all jar files and jnlp file and everything seems to be perfect Any suggestion.

Comment: *"Any suggestion."*  1) Post an URL to the actual JNLP. 2) Ask a (specific) question.

Comment: Actual URL is http://gomez.raleigh.ibm.com/qit/devel/fester/qit_fester.jnlp   This can only be accessible if you are in ibm intranet and I am able to access this url it is just not being accesed if I removed <offline-allowed> from my JNLP file

Comment: *"if I removed <offline-allowed> from my JNLP file"* And... does it work if you ***don't*** remove the `<offline-allowed>` flag?

Comment: Yes, it does work if I don't remove <offline-allowed>, but in that case I have to update my application using the browser, all I want my application to be update using the desktop shortcut.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have checked my JNLP file using JaNeLA and found no error with that, even JaNeLA is able to access the jnlp file from the server

Comment: OK.  Next step.  Search the bug database and if you do not see anything similar, raise a new one.

Comment: @Thanks Andrew, Could you please let me know which bug database I need to search and raise the ticket

Comment: Try the first hit in Google for 'bug database'.